# Ansible regex tomcat version

Tags: ansible

I'm struggling with an issue for some hours now, I want in tasks file to do an action only for a specific version of tomcat, exemple :

```
- name: Copy new context.xml(Manager App) for tomcat8 or 9
  template:
    src: templates/tomcat8-9/manager/context.xml
    dest: /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
    owner: tomcat
    group: tomcat
  when: "{{ tomcat_ver }}" is match("^[8-9]")
```

If my tomcat_ver is 9.0.20 then it should match the pattern but I'm getting a strange error, I don't see where I'm missing any quote

```
 fatal: [tomcatbis]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  did not find expected key\n\nThe error appears to be in '/projects/ansibles/roles/tomcat/tasks/tomcat-setup-Debian.yml': line 69, column 28, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    group: tomcat\n  when: \"{{ tomcat_ver }}\" is match(\"^[8-9]\")\n                           ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like below:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: plat
      debug:
        msg: "Success"
      when: '"{{ tomcat_ver }}" is match("^[8-9]")'
```

**single quotes at the start and at the end**

Comment: @DukagjinBljakaj kindly accept the answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [version comparison test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison)

```
when: tomcat_ver is version('8', '==') or
      tomcat_ver is version('9', '==')
```

(not tested)